# Magento 2 Product Searching Not Working

Tags: magento2.2, catalogsearch

When I'm searching for the product name **"Dell"** then getting products which don't have any word "Dell" in the product name.

**e.g-** I'm **getting following product name when searching for "Dell":-**

**1- "TRANSCEND JETFLASH GO 300 64GB USB 3.0 (3.1 GEN 1) USB TYPE-A CONNECTOR BLACK USB FLASH DRIVE"**

**2- "SANDISK ULTRA MICROSDHC 32GB UHS-I + SD ADAPTER 32GB MICROSDHC UHS-I CLASS 10 MEMORY CARD"**

Similarly **when I searched "Lenovo"** then getting the following:-

**1-"LENOVO KEYBOARD NON-BACKLIT L440/L450/T440/T450 US INT"
2-"LENOVO 04X0324 DISPLAY NOTEBOOK SPARE PART"
3-"MICROBATTERY MBI51069 LITHIUM-ION 4400MAH 10.8V RECHARGEABLE BATTERY"**

But there shouldn't be products which don't contain "Lenovo". means the product **"MICROBATTERY MBI51069 LITHIUM-ION 4400MAH 10.8V RECHARGEABLE BATTERY"** shouldn't be in the search result.

According to my requirement, if any product doesn't contain any word in their name during search then it shouldn't be displayed in the search result.

In the case of "Dell", my search result didn't display any "Dell" related product name.so there should be an empty result.

**Please visit here:-**

http://nimb.ws/87NOM6

http://nimb.ws/UapEsK

So please help me to fix the issue.

--
Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm also facing this same issue. How did you resolved this? Please help!

Comment: sorry, due to some reason I never work on it further.there are some default searching settings in Magento you can check them, or if you're using any 3rd party extensions then check there settings, maybe your issue can resolve.

Comment: did you found any solution for this?